# fwrite , fputs byte safe

Tags: php, .net, post, fputs

I want to send data via POST to a php page, I need to store the bytes exactly as they are but I wasn't able to do it. When I send 138 bytes, fputs and fwrite returns 133.

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'ab') or die("can't open file");
echo fputs($fh, $_POST['data'] ,strlen($_POST['data']));
fclosw
```

VB.NET:

```
Dim ar As System.Text.UTF8Encoding = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
Request.ContentLength = ar.GetByteCount(PostData)
ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
SW = New StreamWriter(Request.GetRequestStream(), ar)
SW.Write(PostData)
```

-edit
this is the encrypted data function

```
Public Function Encrypt(ByVal stringToEncrypt As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    Rijndael.Key = SHA256.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key))
    Rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
    Dim Buffer As Byte() = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt)
    Return Convert.ToBase64String(Rijndael.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0,  Buffer.Length))
    End Function
```

EDITED
example, original encrypted string:

```
j/aokbSUDP1nAD7KafnDoLSmI93sOLiroTwcQIUS/Xw8eUlUZA58OULXCtsnkKqOe+UXlFP6vKuTIWxVMRBZLiBiIOZomNsvoIfM4dv2UzAk2q5mpjo4/0E9lPvu4I7X
```

after sending

```
j/aokbSUDP1nAD7KafnDoLSmI93sOLiroTwcQIUS/Xw8eUlUZA58OULXCtsnkKqOe UXlFP6vKuTIWxVMRBZLiBiIOZomNsvoIfM4dv2UzAk2q5mpjo4/0E9lPvu4I7X
```

Comment: Encrypted how? Can you add an example?

Comment: I meant an example of sent data (just a fictive one). And why do you use the `length` parameter in `fputs` anyway? Are `magic_quotes_*` on?

Comment: Both strings are only 128 bytes, not 133 or 138, as you stated. Moreover, your string is URL-encoded (with `%20` → `+`, as required per spec for `POST` requests), isn't it decoded to a normal string?

Comment: Why is it not decoded automatically?

Comment: Sorry the two samples were flipped i corrected them, the extra bytes for the end-of-line characters

Comment: Still, why do you explicitly specify a `length`? That's not needed and it might be the cause of your problem. Please remove that parameter and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why this wouldn't work:

```
$connection = fopen($file, 'ab');
fwrite($connection, urldecode($_POST['data']));
fclose($connection);
```